# Conditional Formatting - sheet

Tags: excel-formula

I need to make a conditional formatting that it will check the values that are on a worksheet named under Date (02-07-2021). The same date is at the other sheet as a cell that need to change it with an other color if the condition meet.
But is not working... Can someone help me with the code?
I was trying to retrieve the name of the tab and use it with the code, as the condition is between two tabs.

Thank you

```
=COUNTA((MID(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1))+1;256))!$B$2:$F$6;(MID(CELL("filename";A1);FIND("]";CELL("filename";A1))+1;256))!$B$10:$F$13)=45
```

Comment: Yiassou Makis - can I check what you mean by "named under Date..." - basically, the sheet name = Date 02.07.21, right?

Comment: Yiassou! Yes the sheet name is 2-7-2021 and is created when I double click the date at calendar. It created from a template, where I need to insert data. When all the data are entered , at a specific range , then the day at the calendar must be turn red in order to understand that that day is completed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

First thing is first - your functions aren't working in Excel for following key reasons/remedies: (new file [here](https://1drv.ms/x/s!AsxYl9DXJ0j96392rZu8kyG1o4D3?e=yPhqcQ))

1. Exchange all semi-colons (as req.) with common, well, comma discipline ☺
2. You can't have two statements/equations to together without a commma, or without some clear reason

Here's a working solution - you'll need to adapt/amend as req. to suit your purposes (e.g. you may not enquire

```
=COUNTA((MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256)+$B$2:$F$6+(MID(CELL("filename",A1),FIND("]",CELL("filename",A1))+1,256))*($B$10:$F$13)=45))
```

worth stressing - you will most likely need to adapt equation above to your requirements.

This just corrects syntax mainly....

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply. In Greece (region) it is ; and not , so that's why I change them. I can try the above code (I will place is with corrections into conditional formatting). If I can upload somewhere the code or even the excel you will understand what I am talking about. It is a little bit complicated.

Comment: see my update - i have a file linked there- you can edit it and i will see changes if you wish my brother.  Otherwise best of luck :)

Comment: As you want this to apply in conditional formatting, are you hoping to see a '1' or '0' based upon your criteria?  (if so - separate =(condition 1) * ( condition 2) * ()()().... that way you have = (True) * (False) * ,,, etc. and the Trues are evaluated as '1' and False:= 0 so if any are False you will get 0 overall.

Comment: @Patos - were you still stuck or did this end up resolving? upvoting/downvoting/accepting can help future users.  as you deem fit.